# How to do annotating correctly in Vue2.x Class component with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, vue-class-components

I've adopted my project with `@vue/composition-api`

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

But when setting `setup()` in a Class Component,

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ComputedRef, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

function useName(): { name: ComputedRef<string> } {
  const name = ref('Joe')
  return { name }
}

@Component({
  setup() {
    const { name } = useName()
    return { name }
  }
})
export default class TestName extends Vue {}
</script>
```

I always get a warning message like:
[image]

I know that comes from the missing property definition in regular `data` field in Class Component. But by using `@vue/composition-api`, we actually don't need to set the `data` property.

Is there anyone knows how to how to solving the issue.

Comment: Please, don't post the code as images. It's incorrect to do what you're trying to do. Don't mix classes with composition API, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: hi @EstusFlask  thanks for your reply.
I know that Composition API is not mainly for Class Components and may not be recommended to mixed up. But there's a huge codebase of Class Components in my projects. I'm trying to gradually migrate from Vue2.x to Vue3. Would you mind give me any advice?

Comment: It's not just mainly, it's not for class components at all. Use either one or another. Rewrite components to use composition API instead of classes one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works without error in a **Vue** project, but your screenshot of the browser console shows that you're using **Nuxt**.

To use the Composition API in Nuxt, install [`@nuxtjs/composition-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/composition-api) (which includes `@vue/composition-api`, so need to explicitly install it):

```
npm i -S @nuxtjs/composition-api
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js`, add it as a build module:

```js
module.exports = {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module'
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  
I've tried @nuxtjs/composition-api. It doesn't really works well. The original warnings fixed but some others show up  
The roots cause must be something within the Class Component and TypeScript Types. I decide to wait the vue-class-component@v8 which declared to support Compoistion API better.